# how to click in href link with selenium-java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, automation, href

i'm working with selenium-java to automate some tests (it's self learning). I'm stuck in click a hyperlink, but this href is pretty particular, because like this:

```
<a tabindex="-1" href="../../myWebPage.html"><span>My Web Page</span></a>
```

My java code is:

1.- `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='../../myWebPage.html']")).click();`
  2.- `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='https://RealHost/pag1/myWebPage.html']")).click();`

The second option that i used is with the real link, but non of them is working.

Could you please help me?

P.S: I also used the option `driver.findElement(By.LinkText("https://RealHost/pag1/myWebPage.html")).click();` but without success.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to locate the link element by first finding its parent element by looking through the DOM and getting the xpath for that.
Then use that parent element to find elements with a tag of "a"

```
WebElement parent = findElement(By.xpath("/*path to parent element here*/"));
parent.findElement(By.tagName("a")).click();
```

Note that the parent element may have multiple children of tagName "a" if that is the case use findElements() to get a collection of all the hyperlinks with that parent. Then search the collection for the one you want.

```
WebElement parent = findElements(By.xpath("/*path to parent element here*/"));
List<WebElement> elements = parent.findElements(By.tagName("a")).click();
//search the list for the correct link
```

Another thing you could try would be to locate the element by linkText.

```
findElement(By.linkText("/*The hyperlinks text*/")).click();
```

hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try either of the xpath.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'/myWebPage.html')]//span[text()='My Web Page']")).click();
```

OR

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[.//span[text()='My Web Page']]")).click();
```

OR css selector

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='/myWebPage.html']>span")).click();
```

Comment: in this code, driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href*='/myWebPage.html']>span']")).click();, >span is correct or not?

Comment: @DonGonzaloCortezMayer: Sorry mistake.remove the end brackets.Just updated now.

Comment: with the first solution, i got an error: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element is not displayed

Comment: Provide some waits before interacting the element.How about other two options?

Comment: the last option, i got error too: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:17894

Comment: in the middle option i got error too: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: Element is not displayed

Comment: I would suggest provide some wait before you interacting element.the error is clearly mentioned element is not intractable it’s require some time to interact.refer the explicit wait https://www.guru99.com/implicit-explicit-waits-selenium.html

Comment: i've tried with this cocde, but fails too: new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Crear Pago Saliente"))).click();

Comment: Use partiallinktext with And pass Saliente.

Comment: new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Crear Pago Saliente"))).click(); with this works fine!!! Thanks for the help dude

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("My Web Page"))).click();
```

i added a wait overe the element to be clickable and it's works

Thanks guys for your help.

Bye

Answer (score 0):

this works fine for IE driver, but with Chrome is failing due to:

stale element reference: element is not attached to the web page

Help please!